# Debian/Grub2: Moving root partition to new drive?

Tags: debian, grub2

Does anybody have a suggestion for how to move the root partition to a new drive and set up grub2 to boot on that drive? I seem to have no luck instructing grub-mkconfig what it is I want to do (e.g. chroot'int into my new root just confuses all the scripts).

**Background** I am running Debian Squeeze on a headless low-power NAS. My current setup is `/` on `sda0` and `/boot` on `sde0` (a CF card): I needed the separate `/boot` because `sd[a-d]` need to do a delayed spin-up. Now I've found an old 2.5" IDE disk to use as `/` including `/boot` to allow me to spin all the big disks down.

**What I've tried** Basically I went

```
mount -o rw /dev/sdf5 /mnt/newroot
cp -ax / /mnt/newroot
cp -ax /boot /mnt/newroot/boot
```

Then I tried

```
chroot /mnt/newroot
update-grub
```

But that failed with grub asking if root was mounted.
Then I did a half-hearted attempt at setting up `/mnt/newroot/grub/grub.cfg` to find the kernel image on `sdf5`, followed by a `grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/newroot /dev/sdf`. But this just landed me a grub rescue prompt when I tried booting from `sdf`.

My backup plan is to just reinstall, so a bonus question (no checkmarks for this one): What do I have to do to get my lvm2 and mdadm config across? Is it all stored in the filesystems (and will it be automatically discovered), or do I need to take of it myself?

**Solution** (thanks to Maciej Piechotka): As Maciej points out, I need to to a proper chroot for all the grub tools to work. For reference, this is how I did it:

```
janus@nasguld:/mnt/newroot$ sudo cp -ax / /mnt/newroot
janus@nasguld:/mnt/newroot$ sudo cp -ax /boot /mnt/newroot
```

All the files are now copied (see [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Hard-Disk-Upgrade/copy.html) for a discussion of copy strategies). Fix the new `etc/fstab` to point to new root:

```
janus@nasguld:/mnt/newroot$ diff -u etc/fstab.old  etc/fstab
    -UUID=399b6a6d-c067-4caf-bb3e-85317d66cf46 /     ext3 errors=remount-ro         0 1
    -UUID=b394b614-a977-4860-bbd5-7862d2b7e02a /boot ext3 defaults                  0 2
    +UUID=b9d62595-e95c-45b1-8a46-2c0b37fcf153 /     ext3 noatime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Finally, mount `dev`,`sys` and `proc` to the new root and chroot:

```
janus@nasguld:/mnt/newroot$ sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/newroot/dev
janus@nasguld:/mnt/newroot$ sudo mount -t proc none  /mnt/newroot/proc
janus@nasguld:/mnt/newroot$ sudo mount -t sysfs none /mnt/newroot/sys
janus@nasguld:/mnt/newroot$ sudo parted /dev/sdb set 5 boot on 
janus@nasguld:/mnt/newroot$ sudo chroot .
```

We are now chrooted to the future root exactly as it will look. According to Maciej, it should be ok to just call `grub-install`, but I did an `update-grub` first to get a look at the generated `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` before installing the bootloader. I am not sure it will be automatically updated?

```
root@nasguld:/# update-grub
root@nasguld:/# grub-install /dev/sdb
```

Comment: Post the contents of `/etc/default/grub`, and the exact transcript from `update-grub`.

Comment: (thoughts after adding solution): It might actually be that the problem was that I hadn't updated `/etc/fstab` in the `chroot` (this would be consistent with `update-grub` complaining that "\ isn't mounted"). Were I to do this again, I would try first without bothering to mount the special file systems in the chroot.

Comment: just a note: do not forget to unmount /mnt/newroot before reboot!

Comment: Here are instructions on how to move your root partition / to new nvme drive, while keeping the /home on hdd.
http://lucasmanual.com/blog/moving-root-partition-to-nvme-while-keeping-home-on-hdd/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Mount basic filesystems and copy/modify files while chrooting like:

- /dev (`mount -o bind /dev/ /path/to/chroot/dev`)
- /proc (`mount -t proc none /path/to/chroot/proc`)
- /sys (`mount -t sysfs none /path/to/chroot/sys`)

IIRC that worked for me while installing Grub 2 in arch and numerous times on Gentoo. Then after chroot to `/path/to/chroot` command was simply:

```
grub-install /dev/<boot_disk>
```

---

As of lvm2 (and I belive madm but I haven't used it) the configuration is stored on disk. There is configuration what should be read to discover devices. Assuming your devices are in standard locations (`/dev/sd*` or `/dev/hd*`) there should be no problem.

---

PS. I would not trust simple cp of live system as there are several places where it can go wrong:

- Forgot to change `/etc/fstab` and other useful files
- Files changed during access
- Coping garbage (`/tmp` etc.)

Comment: Thanks. So basically, you are saying I do a sloppy chroot :) I'll give it a try with a proper chroot. `cp -ax` should be fine (maybe after dropping to single user runlevel) according to this old howto: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Hard-Disk-Upgrade/copy.html

Comment: Worked a charm! Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Janus: I'd copy data from Live distro to be on safe side. I'm glad however it worked.

Comment: I had to do `update-grub` before `install-grub`.

Answer (score 4):

you can install grub from live distro without chrooting:

```
grub-install /dev/hda --root-directory=/mnt/guest/
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure this would work here: as I understand it, `grub-install` only updates the grub image files and writes the MBR: In particular, `grub.cfg` is not updated. As I commented above, mounting the special dirs might be overkill, but I still think the chroot is the way to update `grub.cfg` in a simple way?

Comment: Yes, this didn't work for me either. You have to get `update-grub` to work and that one does not have `--root-directory` or something, no?

Answer (score 1):

BTW if you are adding a partition (like a windows) on which you don't want grub to write a in the boot sector, but you want grub to know about it when your computer boots, you can re-scan the partitions and generate a new grub.cfg file by using the grub_mkconfig command as follows in a terminal session

> cd /boot/grub
>
> sudo cp grub.cfg ./grub.cfg.old
>
> sudo grub_mkconfig -o ./grub.cfg

Now when you boot off of your current linux partition (that had grub booting it) it will now know about the other partition.