# Move root partition but keep boot

Tags: linux, partition, grub2, gentoo

System: Gentoo linux with Grub2.

I got new ssd drive, so I want to move `root` partition to this device. At moment I have these partitions:

```
/dev/sda1       2048      6143      4096     2M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2       6144    268287    262144   128M EFI System
/dev/sda3     268288   8388607   8120320   3.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4    8388608 134217727 125829120    60G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  134217728 974676015 840458288 400.8G Linux filesystem
```

where `sda2` is `boot` partition, `sda3` - `swap`, `sda4` - `root`, `sda5` is `lvm` device.

New drive is fully managed by `lvm`. New root partition located at `/dev/samsung-ssd/root`. I've already changed `/etc/fstab` on new root.

I've read this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5318, but it suggests to move `boot` partition with `root` to new device, where I want to keep `boot` on old disk.

I tried to edit `grub.conf` and replace kernel boot option from `root=/dev/sda4` to `root=/dev/samsung-ssd/root`, but got a kernel panic (failed to find root partition).

So my question is how to move root partition to new drive and keep boot partition on old?

Comment: You do not really need a separate /boot partition with newer kernels. It is far easier to manage that way.

Comment: As Scyid said, you need to create a initramfs with support for LVM and also tell GRUB to include LVM support. See https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/LVM#Using_LVM_in_an_initramfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, if it is gentoo than you should make your initramfs LVM "aware"…

So, first generate the initramfs with:

```
root# genkernel --lvm initramfs
```

Than add this to your grub configuration (`/etc/default/grub`):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="dolvm"
```

And update the grub (`update-grub` ? I'm not sure…).

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem. To update grub I've used `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`